# Why my button in GUI interface is missing?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def menu():
    print("\nWelcome to File-101: "
    "\n1. Add new item"
    "\n2. Show all item"
    "\n3. Modify item"
    "\n4. Search item"
    "\n5. Delete item"
    "\n6. End Program"
    "\n")
    choice = int(input("Enter menu selection: "))

    return choice
def main():

    main_screen = Tk()   # create a GUI window 
    main_screen.geometry("500x500") # set the configuration of GUI window 
    main_screen.title("Account Login")
    
    valueQuiz = tkinter.StringVar()
    valuePresentation = tkinter.StringVar()
    valueLabExam = tkinter.StringVar()
    valueAssigtment = tkinter.StringVar()

    assesment = ['Quiz','Presentation', 'Lab Exam', 'Assigtment']
    Label(text="Number of Assesment", bg="gray", width="300", height="2", font=("Calibri", 13)).pack()
    inputass = []

    Label(text=assesment[0], width="300", height="2", font=("Calibri", 13)).pack() 
    Entry(textvariable = valueQuiz, width = 25).pack()
    inputass.append(valueQuiz)

    Label(text=assesment[1], width="300", height="2", font=("Calibri", 13)).pack() 
    Entry(textvariable = valuePresentation, width = 25).pack()
    inputass.append(valuePresentation)
    
    Label(text=assesment[2], width="300", height="2", font=("Calibri", 13)).pack() 
    Entry(textvariable = valueLabExam, width = 25).pack()
    inputass.append(valueLabExam)

    Label(text=assesment[3], width="300", height="2", font=("Calibri", 13)).pack() 
    Entry(textvariable = valueAssigtment, width = 25).pack()
    inputass.append(valueAssigtment)

    #button below here did not show up
    Button(main_screen,text='Confirm',width="300", height= "2",command = menu()).pack()

main()
```

Comment: please rearrange your question such that code is in the correct format + add the tkinter window it's producing.

Comment: Avoid using `input()` in a GUI application. Also `command=menu()` will execute `menu()` immediately, not when the button is clicked.  It should be `command=menu`.  And returning value in a callback executed by a button click is meaningless.  Finally you need to call `main_screen.mainloop()` at the end of `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
def main():
   def menu():
    pass
   main_screen = Tk()   # create a GUI window 
   main_screen.geometry("500x500") # set the configuration of GUI window 
   main_screen.title("Account Login")

    valueQuiz = tkinter.StringVar()
    valuePresentation = tkinter.StringVar()
    valueLabExam = tkinter.StringVar()
    valueAssigtment = tkinter.StringVar()

     assesment = ['Quiz','Presentation', 'Lab Exam', 'Assigtment']
     Label(text="Number of Assesment", bg="gray", width="300", height="2", font=("Calibri", 13)).pack()
     inputass = []

      Label(text=assesment[0], width="300", height="2", font=("Calibri", 13)).pack() 
      Entry(textvariable = valueQuiz, width = 25).pack()
       inputass.append(valueQuiz)

     Label(text=assesment[1], width="300", height="2", font=("Calibri", 13)).pack() 
     Entry(textvariable = valuePresentation, width = 25).pack()
     inputass.append(valuePresentation)

      Label(text=assesment[2], width="300", height="2", font=("Calibri", 13)).pack() 
      Entry(textvariable = valueLabExam, width = 25).pack()
      inputass.append(valueLabExam)

      Label(text=assesment[3], width="300", height="2", font=("Calibri", 13)).pack() 
      Entry(textvariable = valueAssigtment, width = 25).pack()
      inputass.append(valueAssigtment)

       #button below here did  show up
        Button(main_screen,text='Confirm',width="300", height= "2",command = menu()).pack()
         main_screen.mainloop()
```